# How do I exclude NULL rows from join result

Tags: mysql

Below are the tables t1 and t2 that I want to generate the output table from. 
My struggle was to not include in the output the rows where `y1` is `NULL`.

```
+--------------+  +--------------+  
|      t1      |  |      t2      | 
+--------------+  +--------------+
| x0 | x1 | x2 |  |  x0  |   y1  |    
+--------------+  +--------------+
| a  | 10 | a  |  |  a   |  haha |
| b  | 11 |NULL|  |  b   |  NULL |
| c  | 12 | c  |  |  c   |  foo  |
| d  | 13 |NULL|  |  d   |  NULL |
+--------------+  + -----+-------+

+--------------+
|    output    |
+--------------+
|  x0  |  y1   |
+--------------+
|  a   |  haha |
|  c   |  foo  |
+--------------+
```

I tried:

```
SELECT t1.x2, t2.y1
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.x0 = t2.x0
```

Also: In some cases my rows don't say `NULL` but are just empty cells.

Comment: You already basically have the answer in your question text. You don't want rows "where y1 is NULL" so `where y1 is  NOT NULL`.

Comment: Probably `WHERE t1.x2 IS NOT NULL AND t2.y1 IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
SELECT t1.x2, t2.y1
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.x0 = t2.x0
WHERE y1 IS NOT NULL AND y1 <> ''
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that my table does not really say `NULL`. I just have an empty cell. How would that translate in a `WHERE` clause? Because when I tried it, all rows were still retrieved.

Comment: @oaklander114 I updated my answer to work for both NULL and empty strings. Can you update your question to reflect the need to also check empty strings?

Comment: `WHERE (t1.x2 IS NOT NULL OR t1.x2 <> '') AND (t2.y1 IS NOT NULL OR t2.y1 <> '')`

Comment: Sorry `OR` should be `AND`

Comment: `WHERE y1 IS NOT NULL AND y1 <> ''` is the same as `WHERE y1 <> ''` neither returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

**This:**

```
SELECT
t1.*,
t2.*
FROM t1, t2
WHERE
(t1.x2 IS NOT NULL AND t1.x2 <> '') AND (t2.y1 IS NOT NULL AND t2.y1 <> '')
```

**Will give you:**

```
'1', 'a', '10', 'a', '1', 'a', 'haha'
'1', 'a', '10', 'a', '4', 'd', 'foo'
```