# How do I Exclude Rows When All Correlated Subqueries Return Null

Tags: sql-server-2012, null, subquery

I have a list of parts from a supplier and I want to see what we've bought and sold since Jan 1. I created subqueries for the sales and purchasing info.

There are four possibilities in the results:

1. Sales Quantity = Purchase Quantity
2. Sales Quantity > Purchase Quantity (including NULL Purchase Quantity)
3. Sales Quantity < Purchase Quantity (including NULL Sales Quantity)
4. Both Sales and Purchase Quantities are NULL

How do I exclude rows when both Sales and Purchase Quantity is NULL while retaining those rows which may have a NULL Sales Quantity or Purchase Quantity? An image is attached to show examples of these scenarios.

I reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575896/how-do-i-exclude-null-rows-from-join-result) thread, but it does not seem to apply because my columns do not have to be equal.

```
SELECT DISTINCT       
p21_view_supplier.supplier_id AS [Supp ID],
p21_view_supplier.supplier_name AS Supplier, 
p21_view_inv_mast.item_id AS [Item ID], 
p21_view_inv_mast.item_desc AS [Item Desc],
p21_view_inv_loc.location_id AS [Location ID],
invoice_data.[Total Shipped by Sales Loc],
purchase_data.[PO Qty Ordered]

FROM            
p21_view_supplier 
INNER JOIN p21_view_inventory_supplier ON p21_view_supplier.supplier_id = p21_view_inventory_supplier.supplier_id 
INNER JOIN p21_view_inv_mast ON p21_view_inventory_supplier.inv_mast_uid = p21_view_inv_mast.inv_mast_uid
INNER JOIN p21_view_inv_loc ON p21_view_inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = p21_view_inv_loc.inv_mast_uid
--Invoices
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT        
    p21_view_invoice_hdr.sales_location_id, 
    p21_view_invoice_line.item_id,
    p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id, 
    p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid, 
    SUM(p21_view_invoice_line.qty_shipped) AS [Total Shipped by Sales Loc]

    FROM            
    p21_view_invoice_hdr 
    INNER JOIN p21_view_invoice_line ON p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_no = p21_view_invoice_line.invoice_no

    WHERE        
    (p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102))

    GROUP BY
    p21_view_invoice_hdr.sales_location_id, 
    p21_view_invoice_line.item_id, 
    p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id,
    p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid
    ) invoice_data ON p21_view_supplier.supplier_id = invoice_data.supplier_id
        AND p21_view_inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = invoice_data.inv_mast_uid
        AND p21_view_inv_loc.location_id = invoice_data.sales_location_id
--Purchasing
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT        
    p21_view_po_hdr.supplier_id, 
    p21_view_po_hdr.location_id AS [PO Loc ID], 
    SUM(p21_view_po_line.qty_ordered) AS [PO Qty Ordered], 
    p21_view_po_line.item_id AS [Item ID],
    p21_view_po_line.inv_mast_uid

    FROM            
    p21_view_po_hdr 
    INNER JOIN p21_view_po_line ON p21_view_po_hdr.po_no = p21_view_po_line.po_no

    WHERE        
    (p21_view_po_hdr.date_created >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (p21_view_po_hdr.delete_flag IS NULL OR
                             p21_view_po_hdr.delete_flag = 'N') 
    AND (p21_view_po_line.delete_flag IS NULL OR
                             p21_view_po_line.delete_flag = 'N') 
    AND (p21_view_po_line.cancel_flag IS NULL OR
                             p21_view_po_line.cancel_flag = 'N') 
    AND (p21_view_po_hdr.cancel_flag IS NULL OR
                             p21_view_po_hdr.cancel_flag = 'N')

    GROUP BY 
    p21_view_po_hdr.supplier_id, 
    p21_view_po_hdr.location_id, 
    p21_view_po_line.item_id,
    p21_view_po_line.inv_mast_uid
    ) purchase_data ON p21_view_supplier.supplier_id = purchase_data.supplier_id
        AND p21_view_inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = purchase_data.inv_mast_uid
        AND p21_view_inv_loc.location_id = purchase_data.[PO Loc ID]

WHERE        
(p21_view_supplier.supplier_id = 8761)
AND (p21_view_inv_mast.delete_flag = 'N')

ORDER BY 
p21_view_inv_mast.item_id,
p21_view_inv_loc.location_id
```

Comment: Assuming I understand the question and assuming supplier_id is not a nullable column, why not just add to your outer where clause `and NOT (purchase_data.supplier_id is null and invoice_data.supplier_id is null)`?

Comment: @ZoharPeled, thank you, that solved it! I should have thought of that...

Comment: Glad to help! I'll copy my comment to an answer later so that you can accpet it and let people know that the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is at least one not nullable column in both of the derived tables, you can simply add a condition to the outer query where clause, that will evaluate to true only if at least one of the non nullable columns in the derived tables is not null.

In this case, I'm assuming that the non-nullable column is the same for both derived tables and it's `supplier_id`, So I add to the where clause the following condition:

```
AND NOT (purchase_data.supplier_id is null and invoice_data.supplier_id is null)
```

The full query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT       
p21_view_supplier.supplier_id AS [Supp ID],
p21_view_supplier.supplier_name AS Supplier, 
p21_view_inv_mast.item_id AS [Item ID], 
p21_view_inv_mast.item_desc AS [Item Desc],
p21_view_inv_loc.location_id AS [Location ID],
invoice_data.[Total Shipped by Sales Loc],
purchase_data.[PO Qty Ordered]

FROM            
p21_view_supplier 
INNER JOIN p21_view_inventory_supplier ON p21_view_supplier.supplier_id = p21_view_inventory_supplier.supplier_id 
INNER JOIN p21_view_inv_mast ON p21_view_inventory_supplier.inv_mast_uid = p21_view_inv_mast.inv_mast_uid
INNER JOIN p21_view_inv_loc ON p21_view_inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = p21_view_inv_loc.inv_mast_uid
--Invoices
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT        
    p21_view_invoice_hdr.sales_location_id, 
    p21_view_invoice_line.item_id,
    p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id, 
    p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid, 
    SUM(p21_view_invoice_line.qty_shipped) AS [Total Shipped by Sales Loc]

    FROM            
    p21_view_invoice_hdr 
    INNER JOIN p21_view_invoice_line ON p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_no = p21_view_invoice_line.invoice_no

    WHERE        
    (p21_view_invoice_hdr.invoice_date >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102))

    GROUP BY
    p21_view_invoice_hdr.sales_location_id, 
    p21_view_invoice_line.item_id, 
    p21_view_invoice_line.supplier_id,
    p21_view_invoice_line.inv_mast_uid
    ) invoice_data ON p21_view_supplier.supplier_id = invoice_data.supplier_id
        AND p21_view_inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = invoice_data.inv_mast_uid
        AND p21_view_inv_loc.location_id = invoice_data.sales_location_id
--Purchasing
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT        
    p21_view_po_hdr.supplier_id, 
    p21_view_po_hdr.location_id AS [PO Loc ID], 
    SUM(p21_view_po_line.qty_ordered) AS [PO Qty Ordered], 
    p21_view_po_line.item_id AS [Item ID],
    p21_view_po_line.inv_mast_uid

    FROM            
    p21_view_po_hdr 
    INNER JOIN p21_view_po_line ON p21_view_po_hdr.po_no = p21_view_po_line.po_no

    WHERE        
    (p21_view_po_hdr.date_created >= CONVERT(DATETIME, '2016-01-01 00:00:00', 102)) 
    AND (p21_view_po_hdr.delete_flag IS NULL OR
                             p21_view_po_hdr.delete_flag = 'N') 
    AND (p21_view_po_line.delete_flag IS NULL OR
                             p21_view_po_line.delete_flag = 'N') 
    AND (p21_view_po_line.cancel_flag IS NULL OR
                             p21_view_po_line.cancel_flag = 'N') 
    AND (p21_view_po_hdr.cancel_flag IS NULL OR
                             p21_view_po_hdr.cancel_flag = 'N')

    GROUP BY 
    p21_view_po_hdr.supplier_id, 
    p21_view_po_hdr.location_id, 
    p21_view_po_line.item_id,
    p21_view_po_line.inv_mast_uid
    ) purchase_data ON p21_view_supplier.supplier_id = purchase_data.supplier_id
        AND p21_view_inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = purchase_data.inv_mast_uid
        AND p21_view_inv_loc.location_id = purchase_data.[PO Loc ID]

WHERE        
(p21_view_supplier.supplier_id = 8761)
AND (p21_view_inv_mast.delete_flag = 'N')
AND NOT (purchase_data.supplier_id is null and invoice_data.supplier_id is null)    
ORDER BY 
p21_view_inv_mast.item_id,
p21_view_inv_loc.location_id
```